# Personality Insights: Is there a rate limit?

Tags: ibm-cloud, personality-insights

We are considering using this API.
However, I do not know how much load the API can withstand.

According to the reference, the API returns 429 if the service is handling content language requests too much.

My question:
How many requests can the API process at the same time?

Content language : Japanese

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem involving code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, the PI API is scaled elastically and can handle any load you give it. If you are planning to send a large load (say over 1M requests a day) - or even if you just need help -, then you should probably be in contact with the team as they can help you with planning for it.